# How to increase image size in matplotlib and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to increase the size of the image resulting from this function:

```
plt.figure()); data_ordertotal.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

I tried this but the size remains the same

```
plt.figure(figsize=(40,40)); data_ordertotal.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

I am coding using spyder and the output in the console remains always the same size. Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you're using pandas, and you should use:

```
data_ordertotal.plot(figsize=(40,40))
```

It doesn't work with `plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))` because pandas will create a new figure if you don't pass it an `axe` object.

It would work with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(40,40))
data_ordertotal.plot(ax=ax)
```

...Assuming you're using pandas, if not you should detail a bit more what is `data_ordertotal`

HTH

Answer (score 3):

when you create a figure change the figsize. The dimension are in inches

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(40, 40), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```

That works for me in spyder.

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

should also work

Comment: please post your full source code. Just with those two lines i get a 40*40 figure.